# How to map Converted Currency fields to other systems

Tags: multi-currency, currency

There are a couple of currency fields that we want to map to our commission system but are not appearing on the mapping for the Tool. I'm not sure how Salesforce implements the fields, or if only they exist there for reporting purposes, but I would like to know if possible, how we can include the converted amount into our commission system.

For example, if one of our deals is in 200 MXN, we would like to see the converted amount of 10 USD.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The converted amount is calculated at runtime and as such is not a real field on the sobject available through Describe

The commission tool you are using most likely uses Describe to find SFDC fields available for mapping.

To always export values in USD, you will need:

- New custom fields called something like `MyAmount_USD__c` - of type Decimal
- A trigger (or Process Builder/lightning Flow) that calculates the value of `MyAmount__c` from `Amount` using the currency rate between the record's CurrencyIsoCode (MXN) and USD. Such conversion logic depends on whether you are using dated exchange rates or not

Once you have done this, and data migrated all existing records to have a populated value in `MyAmount__c`, you can map to the Commissions system